# Запросить разрешение на показ PUSH уведомлений в браузере

Tags: javascript, push-уведомления

Использую это [API](https://www.pushengage.com/api/js-async-api/#register-callback-for-new-subscription),
после вызова запроса разрешения на PUSH уведомления  показывает значок что уведомления запрещены : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
 
как сделать что бы спрашивало по нормальному, хотя бы так: 
 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: каждый раз что ли вам его показывать? один раз заблокирвоали, теперь только значок.

Comment: странно что для плантного апи нет поддержки для фаирфокса в андроид. чем не устроил FCM ?

Comment: мне нужно показать один раз, но вместо нормального диалога у меня просто значок что уведомления запрещены, если на него кликнуть тогда появится окно с кнопкой разрешить. А мне нужно сразу окно с кнопкой разрешить

Comment: если вы уже единожды заблокировали уведомления на данном сайте, или вообще их отключили в браузере, то браузер не будет вам каждый раз рисовать это окно. Скиньте там как-нибудь статус блокировки, и покажется окно.

Comment: @teran а можно как то программно сделать, например запросить сброс настроек для сайта ?

Comment: если каждый сайт сможет сбрасывать настройки, то будет весьма забавно, не правда ли? Если пользователь не хочет получать пуши в бразуере, не надо до него докапываться, он их отключил сознательно. Если у него глобального запрета нет, то при первом запросе на вашем сайте вы получите такое окно. Если пользователь разрешит, то ок. Если запретил, опять таки, не надо ему снова пихать никаких окон с запросом рарзрешени. Вы можете проверить статус оповещений. Если заблокировано то выдайте какой нить попап. Но при этом не надо пытаться дергать стоковые окна (интерфейса для этого все равно нет).

Comment: То есть можете егоп опросить самого снять запрет на пуши, отловить событие смены и потом запросить уже разрешение, тогда окошко для  запроса и появится.

Comment: @teran, так при снятии запрета он может и разрешить.